# Failed to load pdf error in angular code?

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf

I want to have a link on my application which when clicked downloads a pdf file saved in the assets folder. When I am clicking the link it is downloading the pdf but on opening it, it is giving the error:

> Failed to load pdf document.

```
<a class = "help-link" download="User-Guide-televiewer" target="_blank" href="/assets/televiewer-file.pdf">
    Help 
</a>
```

Comment: Please add the URL you are accessing the PDF from.

Comment: I have put the entire file in assets folder

Comment: Please show your code and the error you are getting

Comment: @ShilpiDhiman are you accessing the PDF file like `assets/file.pdf`

Comment: Your problem isn't very clear.If the download link works and the file makes it to your computer at that point it's something else entirely. Does the original version of the pdf open? Does your computer flag files downloaded as potentially not safe (Windows does this by default these days)? Are you setting the mime type correctly for the download link? There are many possible causes here.Once the file is downloaded it's not an Angular specific problem. And in general file transferring is outside Angular as well. You are just using the browsers file handling apis @ShilpiDhiman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was manually creating the pdf file with .pdf extension. Nothing wrong with the code. Just the file error.